# How to avoid fetching the sub entities in a relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, relationship, fetch

Assume I have 3 entities, X, Y, Z.

X has a to-many relationship "Ys" pointed to Y, and Z is a sub entity of Y.

In my situation, I want to fetch all the "Y"s of a given X, but I don't want any Z.

Below is my current code:

```
X *anX;
NSSet *my_Ys = [anX valueForKey:@"Ys"];
```

However, I found it does fetch all the Zs, mixed with Ys in the set my_Ys, which is not what I want.

But I haven't come up a professional way to avoid this, except to check the entity name of all the objects in my_Ys in order to filter the set one by one, which I think is kind of slow.

So any one could offer some help? I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using a fetch request to get the Ys you could set 'includesSubentities` to FALSE. As you are retrieving the Y's via the relationship to X, you can't do that, but you should be able to use a predicate on the returned set by comparing the class of an instance of Y:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"class == %@", [Y class]];

NSSet *only_Ys = [my_Ys filteredSetUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: It's not necessary to instantiate an object to get its class.  You can just say `[Y class]` here.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell yes my original answer used '[Y class]' but when I ran a quick test using NSString it only worked with an instance, which made no sense to me. Just tested using an NSManagedObject and it works, so I've edited my answer. Thx.

Comment: `NSString` behavior is due to the implementation of `NSString` as a class cluster; and the fact that you're asking for class equality rather than class membership.

Comment: Right, which explains why 'isKindOfClass' worked when I tried that but not 'isMemberOfClass'.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! And I bet it is better than my DIY filter method.

Answer (score 0):

So, your object graph looks like this

X <--->> Y <---> Z

The nice thing about Core Data is that you generally don't have to worry about pruning your object graph as it will intelligently manage that for you through a mechanism called faulting. Faulting reduces the amount of memory your application consumes. A fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that has not yet been fully realized, or a collection object that represents a relationship:

- A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but
  its persistent variables are not yet initialized.
- A relationship fault is a subclass of the collection class that
  represents the relationship.

Fault handling is transparent—you do not have to execute a fetch to realize a fault. If at some stage a persistent property of a fault object is accessed, then Core Data automatically retrieves the data for the object and initializes the object.

For more information check out Apple's Core Data Programming Guide's [Faulting and Uniquing section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html).